# Using table function in OBIEE RPD (physical layer) and pass parameter from dashboard prompt to it

Tags: sql, oracle, repository, obiee

I have a almost serious problem. Of course there have been some questions in the same concept of mine, but without any result for me, so I am forced to ask again in different words.
(like: 
[Passing parameters to stored procedure in OBIEE 12c rpd from OBIEE 12c dashboard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44923952/passing-parameters-to-stored-procedure-in-obiee-12c-rpd-from-obiee-12c-dashboard)
or 
[table function as physical table in Oracle BI EE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13789824/table-function-as-physical-table-in-oracle-bi-ee)
)

To provide a report, I am supposed to use table function(means select * from table(valueof(NQ_SESSION.var .....)) in OBIEE physical layer, then pass value through dashboard prompt in order to update its specified session variable.

To achieve this matter, I have created a non-system session variable and named it as var. Then I have defined a physical object with 'select' table type in physical layer and put the specified SQL code (in above) in it (and have not done anything in logical layer), then a dashboard prompt is crated with a request variable (and is named with defined session variable's name, means var).

Now I receive error ( [nQSError: 27002] Near  '<'var'>' Syntax error (HY000) ). It is worth mentioning that my made BI answer(analysis) works as alone but gets error when used in dashboard with dashboard prompt.

Dose anyone know where I am wrong?

Thanks

Comment: Does nobody have any ideas or solutions?

Comment: It is also worth mentioning that I have more than one input parameter. Actually I have three input parameters.

Answer (score 0):

I found that where and why I was wrong. The problem was around session variables which I had defined. The reason was that I had used reserved name (to and from) for my variables. I hope this experience be useful for others like me.

Comment: I'd have been surprised if my inputs on variables hadn't worked.